# how to post Nested model Data to action from View in ASP.NET MVC and MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a two models Persons and Skills.

Persons

```
public class Persons{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string attachment {get; set;}
  public List<Skills> Skills {get; set;}
}
```

Skills

```
public class Skills{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int Rate {get; set;}
}
```

My Action Method in Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Persons objpersons, List<IFormFile> files)
        {
}
```

I have created view with scaffolding,
but am unable to pass the skills data to the action method in HttpPost.
so how can I pass the Skills related data to action method with the attachment

Answer (score 1):

When you created a view with scaffolding it will use a foreach loop
this will loop them by name of the property like "Skill.Name" or "Skill.Rate", we don't want that because this way we lose the collection.

this is how it will look when using a **foreach** loop in HTML

[image: foreach loop in HTML]

Using a for loop will take of this because of its naming it like an array, this will take care of your issue

this is how it will look when using a **for** loop in HTML
[image: for loop in HTML]

You can find more on this website on how to post a collection

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pmfawas/Asp-Net-mvc-how-to-post-a-collection/

Hope this solves your issue